# Oracle ADO.NET Managed driver wrong DateTime parsing

Tags: c#, oracle, ado.net, linq-to-entities, oracle-manageddataaccess

I am using ADO.NET Managed driver 18.3 with Entity framework 6 as database first (.edmx file). I am using LINQ language to retrieve data from Oracle database. I experience the wrong DateTime format parsing from the driver itself. Instead of converting year to 2015, it converts it to 15. But on the same dataset other rows are converted ok (see the below two pictures).

Wrong year parsing:

[image: Wrong Year parsing]

Right year parsing:

[image: Right year parsing]

Code where the Oracle query is happening:

```
using (Entities db = new Entities())
{                 
    List<NewDBObject> QueryResult = (from pos in db.POST
                                     join rac in db.RAC on pos.POPID equals rac.POPID           
                                     select new NewDBObject(                       
                                        Post = pos,                                                        
                                        Rac = rac,                                                               
                                     }).ToList();
    return QueryResult;
}
```

The consequence is that when saving to MSSQL database I get the below error:

[image]

I was looking for a solution to somehow determine the datetime format before query to Oracle is executed, but stumbled on the managed driver limitation which is that it does not support Globalization but relies on client local settings:

> https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODPNT/featGlobal.htm#ODPNT437

If I change local computer date format it does not help either. So far the only thing that works is custom function to check if there is an entry in the dataset that has out of bounds years defined and correct them manually.

**Is there any other way to determine datetime format for Oracle Managed Driver? Maybe in web.config or app.config?**

**Or maybe with some extra session based settings in DBContext?**

Comment: The date in the database is stored correctly because, when i execute the specific query on the row that causes problem in SQL*Plus, it shows 2015 for the year.

Comment: Do you use the correct type mapping?  Start with this: https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/DataTypeMapping.html

Comment: Checked that also. The Date is mapped to DateTime in the table and column of .edmx file. I am using some custom edm mapping but not for the date, only for number.

Comment: Please don't paste images. Use formatted code (your code - which is missing). What is your input data?

Comment: When you work with Date data types properly then they are independent of the current client format.

Comment: I have added the code to the above question. The code is very straight forward. I do not know why you downvoted since all the evidence to the question was presented and the question is not related to the code itself but rather to the functionalities of the Oracle Managed Driver.

Comment: What are the values and what are the data types?

Comment: In which part? In the Oracle tables in edmx files that are queried, or in the NEWDBObject that the data is translated to in query? Oracle tables are pretty big one has 24 columns ("pos" object), the other one has 38 columns ("rac" object). On the Oracle side there are number, varchar2, date. Number has different precisions that translate to C# side differently. As I mentioned in the post and in the previous comment, the error was located to specific column and specific data row, that has no indication of beeing any different than other rows that translate correctly.

Comment: Just the value of "pos" or "rac". I don't know which one is the DATE value. Obviously the date value is `0015-02-13 00:00:00`. looks like you inserted a wrong date. Show us how these wrong values where inserted into Oracle.